# A bit of reverse math fun: how to ensure the existence of the ordinal $\omega^\omega$?

Tags: ordinals, reverse-math

Lately I was having some fun with axiomatizing the ordinals. This isn't a research project or anything, just a casual little side task to keep myself busy during the winter holidays.

I started out with the basic axioms to guarantee a linear order:

1. $\forall_x \neg x < x$
2. $\forall_x \forall_y \neg [x <y \lor y<x] \implies x=y$
3. $\forall_{x} \forall_{y} \forall_{z} [x<y \land y<z] \implies x<z$

And the following axiom scheme to guarantee a well-order:

4. $[\exists_x \phi(x)] \implies \exists_y \phi(y) \land \forall_{z: z<y} \neg \phi(z)$

Then I decided to try adding specific axioms ensuring the existence of certain numbers.

Ensuring the existence of $0$ is easy enough: you just need to assume that *there is at least one ordinal*. You don't neccessarily have to assume that it's the minimal ordinal to prove that there *must* be one.  From now on, every axiom will depend on the existence of at least one ordinal.

Similarly, ensuring the existence of ordinals up to (but not including) $n$ simply requires assuming that *there are at least $n$ distinct ordinals*.

To ensure the existence of every finite ordinal, you simply have to add the axiom:

$$A_\omega : \forall_x \exists_y x<y$$

To talk about higher ordinals, it is convenient to first define the following predicates:

$$I^1(x) \equiv \top$$

$$I^{n+1}(x) \equiv \forall_{y: y<x} \exists_{z:y<z} I^{n}(z) \land z<x$$

It turns out that to ensure the existence of ordinals up to (but seemingly not including) $\omega^{n}$, it is sufficient to assume:

$$A_{\omega^n} : \forall_x \exists_{y:x<y} I^n(y)$$

To ensure that every number up to $\omega^\omega$ exists, it is sufficient to assume all the axioms $A_{\omega^1}, A_{\omega^2}, A_{\omega^3}, \cdots,A_{\omega^n},\cdots$.

I tried to achieve the same result with a single axiom, but my imagination failed me. I also can't seem to figure out how to ensure that $\omega^\omega$ and higher numbers must exist. Any tips on how to move forward would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is equivalent with asking: (how) can $\omega^\omega$ or any higher ordinal be uniquely described in first-order logic using only the relation $>$?

Comment: You could *almost* get away with a successor axiom: $$\forall_x\forall_y[\phi(x) \wedge y < x \implies \phi(y)]\big]\implies \exists_z\forall_y [\phi(y) \iff y < z]$$But something has to be added to avoid that pesky paradox (e.g., when $\phi(y)$ is "$y =y$").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it might not be possible using a single axiom. If we consider the structure $(\textrm{Ord},<)$, [only the ordinals $<\omega^\omega$ are first-order definable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326664/what-is-first-order-definable-in-textord-with-just-leq). So there isn't a first-order predicate $\phi$ in this language where $\omega^\omega$ is the least $\alpha$ such that $(\textrm{Ord},<)\vDash\phi(\alpha)$ (otherwise we could define $\omega^\omega$ as "the unique $\beta$ satisfying $\chi(\beta)\equiv\phi(\beta)\land\forall\gamma(\gamma<\beta\implies\lnot\phi(\gamma))$".)

---

What can we do?

- We can formulate "the successor of each ordinal exists": $\forall\alpha\;\exists\sigma\;\forall\xi\;(\alpha<\xi\implies\sigma\le\xi)$
- Along with this we can formulate the successor relation. We don't use the usual set-theoretic graph formulation since ordered pairs aren't in the domain of discourse, but we can construct a formula $\sigma(\alpha,\beta)$ meaning "$\beta$ is the successor of $\alpha$": $$\sigma(\alpha,\beta)\;\equiv\;\forall\xi\;(\alpha<\xi\implies\beta\le\xi)$$
- In a similar way, the addition relation is first-order definable. This construction is apparently much more complex, it appears on page 6 of Itay Neeman's "[Monadic Definability of Ordinals](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eineeman/monadic-def.pdf)".